# How can I fix a bunch of declare commands being spammed when I start a bash session?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell

Whenever I open a bash terminal, regardless of terminal client my output is spammed with a bunch of `declare -x` messages listing off various environment variables. Here's an example:

```sh
declare -x COLORTERM="truecolor"
declare -x COMMAND_MODE="unix2003"
declare -x HISTFILESIZE="57265949261"
declare -x HOME="/Users/(redacted)"
declare -x LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="(redacted)"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="path variable lol"
declare -x PWD="/Users/(redacted)/Downloads"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.uIiqL6BM38/Listeners"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
# etc
```

**Important note:** I am using bash version `5.1.12(1)-release` installed via homebrew at `/usr/local/bin/bash`. I have not had any other problems with this alternate bash install however. When I execute any shell in interactive mode using it's command (like `bash`) I do not receive the output spam.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are seeing tends to happen if there is an `export` by itself on a line in :

- `$HOME/.bashrc`
- `$HOME/.bash_profile`
- `/etc/profile`

#### Here are some steps you can try:

1. The first thing you can try is to type  `export` by itself in a shell prompt to see if it spits out the same output.
2. Then check to see if you have `export` by itself on a line in of those files (*listed above*):

   ```
   grep -HnE $'^( )*export( |\t)*$' $HOME/.bashrc $HOME/.bash_profile /etc/profile
   ```

   (grep command above is checking for the word export by itself preceded or followed by 0 or more spaces or tabs before the end of the line in a manner that would work for a mac and even linux)
3. You can then comment out the line(s) that show up matching in the file(s).